# Unable to access table variable in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I  am passing a datatable from Code to stored procedure in this way.

```
DataTable table = CommonFunctions.ToDataTable(request);
object[] spParams = new object[1];
spParams[0] = table;

DbCommand dbCommand = 
  db.GetStoredProcCommand("OS_UpdateOrgStructureDetails", spParams);
```

I am trying to access this parameter in stored proc.

```
CratePROCEDURE OS_UpdateOrgUnits  
 @table OS_RenameNodeTable READONLY  
AS  
BEGIN  
    UPDATE OrgUnit  
    SET DetailName = ut.NewValue  
    FROM @table ut  
    INNER JOIN OrgUnit ou ON ou.OrgUnitID = ut.OrgUnitID  
END
```

But when the call is made to stored procedure it throws an error.

```
The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol 
stream is incorrect. Table-valued parameter 1 ("@table"), row 0, column 0: 
Data type 0xF3 (user-defined table type) has a non-zero length database name 
specified.  Database name is not allowed with a table-valued parameter, only 
schema name and type name are valid.
```

Not able to resolve the error.

Comment: This might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(SQL.100).aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because of a bug in the SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters method, the TypeName property of the SqlParameter object for the table valued parameter contains the database name (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx, the comment "Table valued parameters not typed correctly").

The fix this you can add this general purpose code right after creating the command:

```
foreach (SqlParameter parameter in dbCommand.Parameters)
{
    if (parameter.SqlDbType != SqlDbType.Structured)
    {
        continue;
    }
    string name = parameter.TypeName;
    int index = name.IndexOf(".");
    if (index == -1)
    {
        continue;
    }
    name = name.Substring(index + 1);
    if (name.Contains("."))
    {
        parameter.TypeName = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Superb.. You saved more time.. Thanks.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one or two table parameters, you don't have to loop through all the parameters. I wrote a function instead and passed that parameter to that function so that it would fix the typename.

This is the function:

```
    Private Sub SetTypeNameForTableParameter(ByRef parameter As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter)
        If parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured Then
            Dim name As String = parameter.TypeName
            Dim index As Integer = name.IndexOf(".")
            If index <> -1 Then
                name = name.Substring(index + 1)
                If name.Contains(".") Then
                    parameter.TypeName = name
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

This is the piece of code where I'm making the call to the database:

```
'Get Parameters in stored proc
            Dim cmd As System.Data.Common.DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("MyStoredProc")
            db.DiscoverParameters(cmd)
            'The first parameter is the return value. Remove it.
            Dim returnValueParam As Data.Common.DbParameter = cmd.Parameters(0)
            cmd.Parameters.Remove(returnValueParam)
            'Set type name for every table parameter
            SetTypeNameForTableParameter(cmd.Parameters(1))
            'Assign values to the parameters
            cmd.Parameters(0).Value = id
            cmd.Parameters(1).Value = mydatatable
            'Execute the command
            db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd)
```