# TVP - Failed to convert parameter value from a SqlParameter to a IEnumerable`1

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a general purpose function which can accept tvp.

I am getting error 'Failed to convert parameter value from a SqlParameter to a IEnumerable`1.'

```
Dim param As New SqlParameter("@parName", GetTVP(lstDates))
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured
sqlProvider.ExecuteNonQueryV2("sp_Save", CommandType.StoredProcedure, param)

                          ---------------------
Public Function ExecuteNonQuery(ByVal spname As String, ByRef returnValue As Integer, ByVal  ParamArray parameterValues() As Object) As Integer

    Dim connection As SqlConnection = Nothing
    Dim transaction As SqlTransaction = Nothing
    Dim command As SqlCommand = Nothing
    Dim r As Integer = -1

    Try

        connection = New SqlConnection(myconnectionString)
        command = New SqlCommand(spname, connection)
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        connection.Open()
        SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command)
        Me.SetParameters(command, parameterValues)
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
        command.Transaction = transaction
        r = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        transaction.Commit()

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally

    End Try

    Return r

End Function
                          ---------------------

Private Sub SetParameters(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand, ByVal parameterValues() As Object)
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each param As SqlParameter In cmd.Parameters
        param.Value = parameterValues(i)
        i += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

**ADDED**

I have updated the code and take the "SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command)" out and now passing parameter as a sqlparameter list. All works fine now :)

***But i like to know why is it working when i have not defined the parameter type to SqlDbType.Structured ? Isn't it required?***

```
Dim par As New List(Of SqlParameter)
par.Add(New SqlParameter("@parName", GetTVP(lstDates))

---------------

  connection = New SqlConnection(myconnectionString)
  command = New SqlCommand(spname, connection)
  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  connection.Open()
  Me.SetParameters(command, parameterValues)
  transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
  command.Transaction = transaction
  r = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
  transaction.Commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass in the signature a list of SqlParameter instead of a list of objects as parameters?

You can do it this way;

```
Public Function ExecuteNonQuery(ByVal spname As String, 
                                ByRef returnValue As Integer, 
                                ByRef parameters As List(Of SqlParameter)) As Integer
```

Then you can loop and add

```
    For Each para As SqlParameter In parameters
        command.Parameters.Add(para)
    Next
```

Check this link out http://geekswithblogs.net/Rhames/archive/2008/10/29/why-you-should-always-specify-the-sqldbtype-for-an-ado.net.aspx. Ideally and recommended that you define the parameter type, however it is not mandatory.

Comment: I have tried with parameter list and got this error : The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Table-valued parameter 1 ("@ParName"), row 0, column 0: Data type 0xF3 (user-defined table type) has a non-zero length database name specified.  Database name is not allowed with a table-valued parameter, only schema name and type name are valid.

Comment: This statement is causing an error in my function "SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command)"

Comment: Try commenting it out, and leave the looping which I posted. It should still get you the result.

Comment: Is this true that because of a bug in the SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters method, the TypeName property of the SqlParameter object for the table valued parameter contains the database name

Comment: I have tried the foreach loop suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921121/unable-to-access-table-variable-in-stored-procedure but getting error sp_Save has too many arguments specified.

Comment: @user1263981 check the parameters being passed, you are passing more then required

Comment: please check the added section of my question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51192/discussion-between-stephen-borg-and-user1263981)